# I want to create a simple log file in php that stores everything about what is happening in the software?

Tags: php, html

I have a project in which I had created the registration form containing attributes username,email,password,confirmpassword,mobilenumber ...the information being registered by the new user by the registration form, I want to see it in my log file...and I want to know how to create log file in php...Below is my registration.php,login.php,style.css code...please help.

**Registration.php:**

```
<?php  
  include('db.php')
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script>
  // Function to check Whether both passwords is same or not. 
            function checkPassword(form) { 
                password1 = form.password.value; 
                password2 = form.confirm_password.value; 
  
                // If password not entered 
                if (password1 == '') 
                    alert ("Please enter Password"); 
                      
                // If confirm password not entered 
                else if (password2 == '') 
                    alert ("Please enter confirm password"); 
                      
                // If Not same return False.     
                else if (password1 != password2) { 
                    alert ("\nPassword did not match: Please try again...") 
                    return false; 
                } 
  
                // If same return True. 
                else{ 
                    alert("Password Match") 
                    return true; 
                } 
            } 
</script>        
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  </div>
  <form method="post" action="registration.php">
  <?php include('error.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="6" minlength="6"placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Confirm password</label>
      <input type="password" name="confirm_password" maxlength="6" minlength="6"placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="tel"  name="mob_number" maxlength="10" minlength="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="registerNewUser">Register</button>
      <button type="default" class="btn" name="cancel" onclick="location.replace('index.php')">Cancel</button>
      <?php include('log.php')?>
    </div>
    <div>
        Already have an account?
            <a class="right" href="login.php">Login</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php include('db.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Login</h2>
  </div>

  <form method="post" action="login.php">
  <?php include('error.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" required="required"  maxlength="6" minlength="6" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="userLogin">Login</button>
      <button type="default" class="btn" name="cancel" onclick="location.replace('index.php')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Please register <a class="right" href="registration.php">Here</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 120%;
    background: #F8F8FF;
  }

  .header {
    width: 35%;
    margin: 50px auto 0px;
    color: #060606;
    background: #c3cfd0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #a4a8ad;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  form, .content {
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  }
  .input-group {
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
  .input-group label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 3px;
  }
  .input-group input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #060606;
    background: #c3cfd0;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .error {
    width: 92%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a94442;
    color: #a94442;
    background: #f2dede;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background: #dff0d8;
    border: 1px solid #3c763d;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .right{
    text-align: right;
  }
```

Comment: I commonly use **[log4php](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/download.html)** for such purposes. If you follow simple examples that are available in many places, setup should be easy enough.  Prefer composer to any other install.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this should help you.

```
<?php echo file_put_contents("test.log","Hello World. Testing!");?>
```

Just pass the data that you want in place of "Hello World. Testing!"